# Функция, которая меняет ячейку в списке

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Есть список из объектов `User` со значениями `name` и `date`, которые в позиции 0 имеют значения `Вася` и `15:37`. Как должна выглядеть функция, которая при вызове будет менять значения в этой ячейке (в позиции `0`) на `Петя` и `15:15`
Вот мой код:

```
class Test {
 private var list = mutableListOf<User>()
    private var user: User? = null

 private fun addItem() {
       
    user = User("Вася","15:37")
    list.add(0, user!!)
}
}
```

в определенном месте кода я вызываю метод `addItem` и у меня появляется ячейка со значениями Вася и 15:37. После этого я хочу вызвать функция, которая поменяет значения в этой ячейке...

Comment: приведённый код изменяет поля первого объекта в списке, из вопроса непонятно что вы пытаетесь достичь

Comment: мне нужна функция, которую я вызвала - и значение в ячейке поменялось. в любой ячейке. например, у меня список из объектов `User`  со значениями `name` и `date`, которые в позиции `0` имеют значения `Вася` и `15:37`. Я вызвала функцию - и значения в этой ячейке в позиции `0` поменялись на `Петя` и `15:15`. Что-то типа этого)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У интерфейса List имеется метод get по индексу, достаточно воспользоваться им:

```
private fun updateCell(position: Int, name: String, date: String, list: List<User>) {
    if(position >= 0 && position < list.size){
      val user = list[position]
      user.date = date
      user.name = name
    }
}
```

Comment: не работает.... ничего не меняется. наверное я не понятно изложила свою проблему. я обновлю вопрос сейчас.

Comment: @Monica пока не вижу чего-то, что неправильно работает, даже с обновлением вопроса, всё должно быть ок. Может быть вывод полей происходит до обновления юзера?

Comment: а что значит до обновления юзера? в какой момент происходит обновление юзера?

Comment: очевидно, когда вы вызываете метод updateCell

Comment: попробовала вывести список. выводит значение `[]kotlin.Unit`

Comment: Вы явно выводите не список, мб результат updateCell?

Comment: ну я просто вызываю функцию updateCell и передаю в нее параметры

Comment: так а выводите список как?

Comment: <https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2021/1/6/54142db3343dac3e2adb023968d6b577-full.png>

Comment: в условии была ошибка, исправил

Comment: работает. спасибо. это именно то,что мне нужно было